# Python not waiting for subprocess to finish?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use Python 3 to run a windows program a number of times with different inputs. To run the program from the command line I use

```
C:\prog -v input_file
```

My python equivalent is

```
args = ['prog','-v', input_file]
subprocess.call(args)
```

I need to wait for `prog` to finish before post-processing the results but something is not quite right.  For example, if I run the program 3 times and write a summary of the results to file I would expect to see this

```
run 1   summary of run 1
run 2   summary of run 2
run 3   summary of run 3
```

but this is what I actually get

```
run 2   summary of run 2
run 3   summary of run 3
run 3   summary of run 3
```

There are a whole bunch of WMIC processes running after I finish the Python script, so maybe these have got something to do with the problem?  Basically, the Python script seems to be getting ahead of itself and doing some of the post-processing too early.  All suggestions gratefully received - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - had a closer look at the code and there was an issue with indenting which affected program flow and thus the way in which the data was written to file.  Still having issues with the WMIC files but will close this issue and open a separate one about the WMIC files